# Get absolute path using FileUploadInputElement

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I need to upload a file using SFTP on flutter web. 
I use FileUploadInputElement to give user the possibility to select the file and then I need to get the absolute path and use it with SFTP. Actually I've no idea how to get it.
I'm able only to print the file name

```
IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.file_upload),
              onPressed: () async {
                final InputElement uploadInput = FileUploadInputElement();
                uploadInput.click();
                uploadInput.onChange.listen((e) {
                  final files = uploadInput.files;
                  if (files.length == 1) {
                    final file = files[0];
                    print(file.name);
                    //Need to get absolute path
                  }
                });
              },
            )
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem like yours, did you find the solution?